# comparing data between different mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am relatively new to Elasticsearch so I apologies if the terms are not accurate. I have a few indexes and a few almost identical indexes but with less fields in the mapping.
(the original indexes has data and the new ones with less fields are empty)
how can I compare the data and insert the relevant documents into the new indexes with less fields?

for example original index mapping:

```
    {
    “first_name” : ”Dana”,
    “last_name” : ”Leon”,
    “birth_date” : “1990-01-09“,
    “social_media” :    {
                    “facebook_id” : ”K8426dN”,
                    “google_id” : ”8764873”,
                    “linkedin_id” : ”Gdna”
                }
}
```

new mapping with less fields

```
{
“first_name” : ”Dana”,
“last_name” : ”Leon”,
“social_media” :    {
                “facebook_id” : ”K8426dN”,
                “google_id” : ”8764873”,
                “linkedin_id” : ”Gdna”
            }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, when say "insert the relevant documents into the new indexes"? Do you mean, that you need to check, is the document have less fields and if yes - to ingest it to the new index? If yes, why you need to separate this documents? BTW Elasticsearch haven't storage/memory overhead in case of null values in the document

Comment: @Vakhtang i mean copy the documents from the old index with more fields to the new index with less fields, i dont need to separate them just to copy the data minus the data where the fields doesnt exist in the destination if that makes sense?

Comment: For clean understanding... your original dicuments have the fields, that you don't want to ingest into the new one?

Comment: yes, exactly the original documents have more fields

Answer (score 1):

You can use reindex by script:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-change-name

In the "script" you'll need to specify the fields, that you want to remove like:

ctx._source.remove("birth_date")"

The second option is to use ingest pipeline with "remove" proccessor:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/remove-processor.html, and to do reindex with default pipeline definition into settings, but this will be harder to implement

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. appreciate your help